# Is there a simple way to generate the Erlang Thrift files for Cassandra on Windows?

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

It seems that these can only be generated on Unix and then copied over to Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested myself but [this](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftInstallationWin32) page gives instructions how to install Thrift on windows.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I saw that page and realised it is very complicated and error prone.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. This problems is more of a Thrift problem than a Cassandra problem though.